# Unable to Install adldap2/adldap2-laravel package

Tags: laravel

I just created new project in laravel.

```
laravel new ldap
```

After that try to install the package using

```
composer require adldap2/adldap2-laravel
```

I am getting an error like this

```
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - adldap2/adldap2-laravel v6.0.8 requires adldap2/adldap2 ^10.1 -> satisfiable by adldap2/adldap2[v10.1.0, v10.1.1, v10.2.0, v10.2.1, v10.2.2].
    - adldap2/adldap2-laravel v6.0.0 requires adldap2/adldap2 ^10.0 -> satisfiable by adldap2/adldap2[v10.0.0, v10.0.1, v10.0.10, v10.0.11, v10.0.2, v10.0.3, v10.0.4, v10.0.5, v10.0.6, v10.0.7, v10.0.8, v10.0.9, v10.1.0, v10.1.1, v10.2.0, v10.2.1, v10.2.2].
    - adldap2/adldap2-laravel v6.0.1 requires adldap2/adldap2 ^10.0 -> satisfiable by adldap2/adldap2[v10.0.0, v10.0.1, v10.0.10, v10.0.11, v10.0.2, v10.0.3, v10.0.4, v10.0.5, v10.0.6, v10.0.7, v10.0.8, v10.0.9, v10.1.0, v10.1.1, v10.2.0, v10.2.1, v10.2.2].
    - adldap2/adldap2-laravel v6.0.2 requires adldap2/adldap2 ^10.0 -> satisfiable by adldap2/adldap2[v10.0.0, v10.0.1, v10.0.10, v10.0.11, v10.0.2, v10.0.3, v10.0.4, v10.0.5, v10.0.6, v10.0.7, v10.0.8, v10.0.9, v10.1.0, v10.1.1, v10.2.0, v10.2.1, v10.2.2].
    - adldap2/adldap2-laravel v6.0.3 requires adldap2/adldap2 ^10.0 -> satisfiable by adldap2/adldap2[v10.0.0, v10.0.1, v10.0.10, v10.0.11, v10.0.2, v10.0.3, v10.0.4, v10.0.5, v10.0.6, v10.0.7, v10.0.8, v10.0.9, v10.1.0, v10.1.1, v10.2.0, v10.2.1, v10.2.2].
    - adldap2/adldap2-laravel v6.0.4 requires adldap2/adldap2 ^10.0 -> satisfiable by adldap2/adldap2[v10.0.0, v10.0.1, v10.0.10, v10.0.11, v10.0.2, v10.0.3, v10.0.4, v10.0.5, v10.0.6, v10.0.7, v10.0.8, v10.0.9, v10.1.0, v10.1.1, v10.2.0, v10.2.1, v10.2.2].
    - adldap2/adldap2-laravel v6.0.5 requires adldap2/adldap2 ^10.0 -> satisfiable by adldap2/adldap2[v10.0.0, v10.0.1, v10.0.10, v10.0.11, v10.0.2, v10.0.3, v10.0.4, v10.0.5, v10.0.6, v10.0.7, v10.0.8, v10.0.9, v10.1.0, v10.1.1, v10.2.0, v10.2.1, v10.2.2].
    - adldap2/adldap2-laravel v6.0.6 requires adldap2/adldap2 ^10.0 -> satisfiable by adldap2/adldap2[v10.0.0, v10.0.1, v10.0.10, v10.0.11, v10.0.2, v10.0.3, v10.0.4, v10.0.5, v10.0.6, v10.0.7, v10.0.8, v10.0.9, v10.1.0, v10.1.1, v10.2.0, v10.2.1, v10.2.2].
    - adldap2/adldap2-laravel v6.0.7 requires adldap2/adldap2 ^10.0 -> satisfiable by adldap2/adldap2[v10.0.0, v10.0.1, v10.0.10, v10.0.11, v10.0.2, v10.0.3, v10.0.4, v10.0.5, v10.0.6, v10.0.7, v10.0.8, v10.0.9, v10.1.0, v10.1.1, v10.2.0, v10.2.1, v10.2.2].
    - adldap2/adldap2 v10.2.2 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v10.2.1 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v10.2.0 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v10.1.1 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v10.1.0 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v10.0.9 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v10.0.8 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v10.0.7 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v10.0.6 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v10.0.5 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v10.0.4 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v10.0.3 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v10.0.2 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\xampp\php\php.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

my composer.json file

```
 "require": {
        "php": "^7.2",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "^6.2",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0"
    },
```

Not understanding what is the problem

Thank you

Comment: You need to add more details, what is the follow up of those line the composer gave you after **problem 1**. maybe you dont have installed the ext-ldap of php

Comment: ok, I will edit my question. How to install ext-ldap? I am totally new to this

Comment: if you're on ubuntu, `sudo apt-get install php-ldap`

Comment: for Windows XAMPP?

Comment: thank you very very much that was the problem